# Magento 1.9 product view custom options as accordion

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

is there a way of adding a jquery accordion block to the custom options on the product view page.

if there are 5 custom option dropdowns with their own heading title,

can each one have its own title as the accordion tab, and then the actual dropdown with some form of html text inside each one

Comment: Hi Plugger and welcome to MageOverflow! Yes, this is possible. What have you tried? What is your problem?

Comment: I havent tried anything, i dont know where to start to be honest, apart from searching for extensions which i cant seem to find any that will do that

Answer (score 1):

Options are built here: `catalog/product/view/options.phtml`

Epecially here:

```
<dl>
    <?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

So I'm sure this can be achieved. I recommend a Prototype based JS library, so you don't need to load jQuery.